# Use another source address on Linux to a specific destination

Tags: linux, networking, centos, linux-networking, firewalld

I've a Linux box (CentOS 7) with one interface. Its IP is 10.10.0.2. I have an alias IP address too: 10.20.0.2. I'd like to call a webservice from the alias IP address. How can I achieve this? So add the default source address to a specific ip range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to a `SNAT` rule into you `nat` table

```
iptables  -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d DESTIP/PREXFIX -j SNAT --to-source 10.20.0.2
```

or more specific

```
iptables  -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d DESTIP/PREXFIX  -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j SNAT --to-source 10.20.0.2
```